# WebTestClient - CORS with Spring Boot and Webflux

Tags: java, spring-boot, cors, spring-webflux, same-origin-policy

I have Vuejs frontend and a Spring Boot Webflux controller. Now the browser is complaining with CORS when doing a call to Spring Boot.

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://...' from origin 'https://...' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

To enable CORS I tried to use the @CrossOrigin annotation as described here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webflux-cors

But it didn't help and somehow Spring does not send the CORS headers back in the response even with the @CrossOrigin annotation in the controller.

I also tried with the WebTestClient as described in the Bealdung tutorial and it confirms the header is not there:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Response header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' expected:<[*]> but was:<null>

> OPTIONS /cors-enabled-endpoint
> WebTestClient-Request-Id: [1]
> Origin: [http://any-origin.com]
> Access-Control-Request-Method: [GET]

No content

< 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR Internal Server Error
< Vary: [Origin, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers]

0 bytes of content (unknown content-type).
```

If I test with `response.expectHeader().exists("Access-Control-Allow-Origin");`
I get:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Response header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' does not exist
```

Any Idea why CORS configuration as described in the link above does not work? I also tried Enabling CORS on the Global Configuration and Enabling CORS with a WebFilter. But nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use following configuration for the WebTestClient:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient

class MyTestClass {

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @Test
    void corsTest() {
        ResponseSpec response = webTestClient.get()
                .uri("/cors-enabled-endpoint")
                .header("Origin", "http://any-origin.com")
                .exchange();

        response.expectHeader()
                .valueEquals("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    }

}
```

And I also needed to add the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency, which is very strange because I am using only Webflux. But without it the test still fails with `IllegalArgumentException: Actual request scheme must not be null`.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Now, the test is green!

Answer (score 3):

Thinice's solution is 99.9% there.  The Spring WebTestClient CORS testing requires that the URI contain *any* hostname and port.  The *actual* hostname and port is ignored by WebTestClient to connect to the test web server:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
class MyTestClass {

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webTestClient;
    
    @Test
    void corsTest() {
        webTestClient.get()
                .uri("http://hostname-ignored:666/cors-enabled-endpoint")
                .header("Origin", "http://any-origin.com")
                .exchange()   
                .expectHeader()
                  .valueEquals("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    }    
}
```

Furthermore, one can omit the explicit port and it will continue to work:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
class MyTestClass {

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webTestClient;
    
    @Test
    void corsTest() {
        webTestClient.get()
                .uri("http://look-ma-no-port/cors-enabled-endpoint")
                .header("Origin", "http://any-origin.com")
                .exchange()   
                .expectHeader()
                  .valueEquals("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    }
}
```

To enable CORS for all endpoints, one can use the given WebFluxConfigurer:

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class MyWebFluxConfigurer {

  @Bean
  public WebFluxConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebFluxConfigurerComposite() {

      @Override
      public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*").allowedMethods("*");
      }
    };
  }
}
```

- Including the Origin header is important.  Without the Origin header the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header will not be set and the test will fail.
- Setting Origin as the same hostname as the URI will be considered the same origin, so no cross origin headers are set.
- RichArt's suggestion to include the spring-boot-starter-web dependency is not specifically required to enable CORS testing.
- This answer only applies to testing.  It assumes you have enabled CORS in your server.
- My answer is using Spring WebFlux 5.3.10.

Comment: The whole thing that you must add ANY host (`http://whatever`) to the URI is very strange, but it's actually works

Answer (score 1):

For me what actually worked without adding the spring-starter-web dependency was to use a web filter and force return if the http method is **OPTIONS**.

```
@Configuration
public class CorsGlobalConfiguration implements WebFilter {


@Override
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange,
                         WebFilterChain webFilterChain) {
    ServerHttpRequest request = serverWebExchange.getRequest();
    ServerHttpResponse response = serverWebExchange.getResponse();
    HttpHeaders headers = response.getHeaders();
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN, "*");
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS, "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE, PATCH");
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS, "true");
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS, "*");
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_EXPOSE_HEADERS, "*");
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_MAX_AGE, "18000L");
    if (request.getMethod() == HttpMethod.OPTIONS) {
        response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.OK);
        return Mono.empty();//HERE
    }
    return webFilterChain.filter(serverWebExchange);
}


}
```

[Source](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=SophiaLeo%2Fsophia_scaffolding%2Fsophia_scaffolding-master%2Fv3%2Fsophia_scaffolding%2Fsophia_gateway%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Fscaffolding%2Fsophia%2Fgateway%2Ffilter%2FCorsFilter.java)

Answer (score 1):

@RichArt's solution is 99% close - but you don't need the dependency (spring-boot-starter-web); since it's checking CORS, it appears Spring needs help knowing what scheme and host you're hitting it from in the test; it can't derive the 'scheme' (http) or the host with the shorter URI.

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
class MyTestClass {

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @LocalServerPort
    private Int lsp;

    @Test
    void corsTest() {
        ResponseSpec response = webTestClient.get()
                .uri("http://localhost" + lsp.toString() + "/cors-enabled-endpoint")
                .header("Origin", "http://any-origin.com")
                .exchange();

        response.expectHeader()
                .valueEquals("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes adding mvc stuff probably not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

In the [JavaDocs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/CrossOrigin.html) of the `@CrossOrigin` there is mentioning

> Both Spring Web MVC and Spring WebFlux support this annotation through
> the RequestMappingHandlerMapping in their respective modules. The
> values from each type and method level pair of annotations are added
> to a CorsConfiguration

Which means your CORS settings will be added to [CorsConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/cors/CorsConfiguration.html)

If you are using Spring Security you need to [enable CORS](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.3.RELEASE/reference/html5/#cors) so that your CorsConfiguration will be used. See below a small example

```
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .cors()
            ...
    }
```

From the [JavaDocs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#cors--)

> Adds a CorsFilter to be used. If a bean by the name of corsFilter is
> provided, that CorsFilter is used. Else if corsConfigurationSource is
> defined, then that CorsConfiguration is used. Otherwise, if Spring MVC
> is on the classpath a HandlerMappingIntrospector is used.

Note, if you are sending credentials with the request (cookies) you need to add it to your CORS settings

```
@CrossOrigin(allowCredentials = "true")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. After reading it carefully and also reading again the documentation I still have the same problem. Actually, I do not use Spring Security. One more thing: Running the test gives also this error:
`2020-07-04 13:44:45.611 ERROR 17867 --- [     parallel-1] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [38a66881] 500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/cors-enabled-endpoint"`

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Actual request scheme must not be null`

It might be the root cause but I don't find helping resources in the internet. Can you help?

Comment: @RichArt Make sure you put CrossOrigin on the exact same request mapping you are sending the request to. If you put CrossOrigin on GET "/api/users" then CORS will be enabled only for GET "/api/users" . You could also put  CrossOrigin on the controller level then CORS will be available for all request mapping in the controller e.g. POST "/api/users" GET "/api/users" etc. and of course, it will depend on which methods you allowed in CORS configuration in the controller.